# Windows laptop not able to connect to new bluetooth devices - the device just keeps "Connecting" forever

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I recently bought a RC transmitter that has a build-in bluetooth and yesterday I tried to connect it to my pc over the bluetooth instead of a cable and I found out, that my PC can't connect to it and it just shows "Connecting" forever.

This is clearly a fault of my computer, because I tried to connect it to my phone and it works without any problem. I tried to cancel the process and start the connection again, but the joystick didn't show up at all. It didn't show up as a paired device neither. I checked the drivers and the driver for my transmitter showed up. I tried to remove it, but it kept reappearing.

I made a lengthy research and I found out a random solution that I should remove the device in regedit. I tried to remove the device from `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices\` and it actually somehow worked and the RC transmitter was discoverable again but with the same behavior as before.

At this point, I tried to connect my phone to the pc to see what it will do and the behavior was exactly the same. The phone also has the thing that both devices show the same pin on the screen during the pairing process and that worked, so the bluetooth probably isn't totally broken. So, I did even more research and I found somewhere that I should run services.msc and switch the bluetooth support service from manual to automatic and delete the passwords under the log on tab. I tried it and it actually did something (even though i the service was already running before I made those changes).

Instead of being stuck on the "Connecting" label, windows bluetooth settings showed the "Connecting" label only for a few seconds and then they switched to the "Try connecting your device later". I don't have any idea if it is a positive change or a negative change. I tried to revert it (just so I have better understanding on what just happened, but switching the service back to manual and rebooting pc didn't revert the changes, so I switched it back to automatic).

For some reason, despite me not doing anything device specific at this point, this change applies only to the transmitter and not to my phone, that is still stuck on the "Connecting". I also did try to reinstall the Intel Bluetooth driver, but it didn't have any effect. I've also done many many reboots and also lots of other random stuff, but I don't remember it exactly, so I'm not adding it to this post.

I also want to add another thing I've observed but I'm not sure about this, because I didn't pay a special attention to this at the time it happened. Last time I used the bluetooth on my laptop was like 3 weeks ago when I used my smartcube for a while and it was connected from the web browser bluetooth window, not from windows settings.

I remember that when the cube was new, I tried to connect it over windows settings and it failed but I didn't think of it much. Sadly, I don't have the cube with me rn to test if the web browser bluetooth still works and is able to pair new devices and I am not 100% sure if the attempt to connect it via the windows bluetooth panel actually failed, but I think so.

Do you have any other ideas how to fix it? I would be quite happy if they are nondestructive, like I don't think that something like reinstalling the whole pc is a good enough solution (because it's a massive overkill)

Edit: I found out, the changing the service had no effect. It was just a coincidence because the RC transmitter can connect only to one device at a time and I turned on the bluetooth on my phone at the same time.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/fix-windows-10-bluetooth-not-working-4587254 Run the Windows 10 Bluetooth troubleshooter.  To begin the Bluetooth troubleshooter, open the Start menu, then select Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Bluetooth.

Comment: @Gantendo, I already tried running the troubleshooter before making this post and it didn't work at all. Despite this, I tried to run it again and it didn't work but it gave me the same message I got last time. So I tried to run it again and again and it keeps showing "Problems found: Check bluetooth radio status     fixed". I guess that this isn't exactly what I want but idk how to fix this issue so it won't keep reappearing.